# CodeIgniter 4 validation returns errors for FormData submissions

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am attempting to send a simple form via AJAX using FormData in CI4, however I continue to get a 500 error in console, and all of the validation results are negative/null. I have done MULTITUDES of form submissions and validation this way and they have all worked, but I'm not sure where the snag is in this one.

My Routes.php file is setup with the current routes, and my validation has been setup according to the most recent CI version documentation.

Registration Process (Sentry::registration_process)

```
public function registration_process()
    {
        $this->vlad->setRules([ <-- VLAD IS DECLARED IN BASE_CONTROLLER AS VALIDATOR
            'email' => [
                'label' => 'Email Address',
                'rules' => 'valid_email|required'
            ],
            'cr_pass' => [
                'label' => 'Create Password',
                'rules' => 'regex_match[/^(?=.{6,20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+*!=]).*$/]|required'
            ],
            'conf_pass' => [
                'label' => 'Confirm Password',
                'rules' => 'matches[cr_pass]|required'
            ],
            'org_id' => [
                'label' => 'Organizational ID',
                'rules' => 'required'
            ]
        ]);

        if(!$this->vlad->withRequest($this->request)->run())
        {
            $error = '';
            foreach($this->vlad->getErrors() as $e)
            {
                $error .= $e . " || ";
            }

            $error = rtrim($error, " || ");
            return json_encode($error);
        }

        $client_data = array(
            'id' => rand(111, 999999999),
            'email' => $this->request->getVar('email'),
            'password' => password_hash($this->request->getVar('conf_pass'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'organization_id' => $this->request->getVar('org_id'),
            'created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        // $result = $this->hozo->gather_user_credentials($client_data['organization_id']);
        // $result = $this->mod->register_new_client($client_data);
        
        return json_encode($client_data); // <--- THIS IS JUST TO SEE IF THE VALIDATION PROCESS GOES THROUGH
    }
```

Handler JS File (authentication_handler.js)

```
$(function() {

    // $('#authLoginForm').on('submit', function(ev) {
    //
    //     ev.preventDefault();
    //     var form = new FormData(this);
    // });

    $('#authRegisterForm').on('submit', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var form = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/registration_process',
            data: form,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result) {

                console.log(result + " : This is unparsed JSON");

                var r = JSON.parse(result);
                if(r === '1' || r === 1) {

                    console.log(r + " : This is parsed JSON");
                }
            },
            error: function(result) {

                console.log(result + " : This is an ERROR"); <-- AUTOMATICALLY COMES HERE AND RETURNS ALL OF THE CI VALIDATION FAILED MESSAGES
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Register Portal view:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar col-sm-6 bg-dark">
            <div class="auth-main-text text-center">
                <h2 class="display-2 text-rm-blue">Reserve Mutual</h2>
                <p class="leadm text-white">Register your Reserve Mutual/Zoho account to view your accounts &amp; transactions</p>

                <div class="mt-2">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Already registered your Reserve Mutual account?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main col-sm-6">
            <form id="authRegisterForm" class="auth-register-form col-sm-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="yourzoho@email.com" required />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cr_pass">Create Password: <br />
                        <span class="small text-italic text-muted">Create a 6-20 character password with 1 upper &amp; lower letter, and 1 special character (!@#$%^&*.-_),</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cr_pass" required />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="conf_pass" class="small">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="conf_pass" required />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="org_id">Organization ID: <br />
                        <span class="small text-italic text-muted">This is your Zoho Organization ID you received from Reserve Mutual</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="org_id" required />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-dark">Register Account</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Routes.php (section pertaining to the route in question)

```
$routes->post('registration_process', 'Sentry::registration_process');
```

As I said, I have been using this method for sometime now and haven't ever been able to not find out what is going on, but CI has stumped me. I researched and adjusted just about every variable I can think of and used most examples that I have found (some answers didn't really track with my current situation) but nothing seems to stick. Am I missing something simple? Was there an update in CI4 that I was unaware of?

Thanks a bunch for your time!

**UPDATE --**

I checked on XAMPP error log and there was nothing indicating the source of the issue. I can follow the data from the submission, and upon arrival at the method in the class, a `var_dump($_POST)` shows there is data, but the validator says its empty and all fields are required inside the returned AJAX response.

Comment: "a 500 error" is not helpful information. Your server logs will show you the actual problem, and even point you to the problematic line in your code.

Comment: uncomment this line CI_ENVIRONMENT = production in .env file and change it to  CI_ENVIRONMENT = development to  see errors in your application

Comment: @VirenderKumar I haven't used the env file, but in the app/Config/Boot/production.php file I changed the ini_set() to display all errors and the only errors returning are the validation errors from the CI end

Comment: Error 500 usualy accured when there is a problem on the source code. 1. Check the libraries, models or helpers when they are called before the ussage. 2. add error_reporting(E_ALL) to the constructor to see the actual error. 3. Last option is echo then exit line by line to captured the line where the error accured :)